# NHibernate: Denormalized SQL Query mapped to an object

Tags: sql, nhibernate, denormalized

I have this class:

```
public Customer
{
   public int CustomerId {get;set;}
   ....
   public List<Order> OrderList {get;set;}
}
```

I'd like to write this SQL query using NHibernate CreateSQLQuery

```
SELECT C.CustomerId, .... O.OrderId, O.OrderDate, O.OrderTotal.....
FROM Customers C
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Orders O ON C.CustomerID = O.CustomerID
```

How do I make this transformation work:

```
 .SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean<Customer>())
```

And have it contain a list of Orders within each Customer object?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all the column names of your result map to property names of your entity, you may try :

```
var myQuery = @"SELECT C.CustomerId, .... O.OrderId, O.OrderDate, O.OrderTotal.....
                   FROM Customers C
                   LEFT OUTER JOIN Orders O ON C.CustomerID = O.CustomerID";

myNHSession.CreateSQLQuery(myQuery)
           .AddEntity("C",typeof(Customer))
           .AddJoin("O","C.OrderList")
           .List();
```

Hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

Use named queries if you can.

```
<sql-query name="myQuery">
  <return alias="c" class="Customer" />
  <return-join alias="o" property="c.Orders" />
  <![CDATA[
   SELECT {c.*}, {o.*} FROM Customers c LEFT OUTER JOIN Orders o ON c.CustomerId = o.CustomerId
  ]]>
</sql-query>
```

The `{c.*}` and `{o.*}` are understood by NHibernate and replaced with actual columns at session build time. Another advantage is that you can precompile these queries at application startup.

```
  var results = session.GetNamedQuery("myQuery").List<Customer>();
```